# How to include special characters in a Graph API search

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I am trying to encode a '#' sign into a search. The following does not work (as you would expect):

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$search="subject:Ticket #10001"`

Returns the error

`"There is an unterminated string literal at position 15 in '\"subject:Ticket'."`

According to the documents we need to precent-encode the '#' character, however that does not seem to work either:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$search="subject:Ticket %2310001"`

Returns exactly the same message. Am I missing something here? What is the correct way to encode special characters for the Graph API?